# How to persist zipkin data in ES 5.0?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, zipkin

**TL;DR:**
I want to persist data in ElasticSearch, how i can do this?

I have zipkin and Kafka and ElasticSearch. Kafka as transport for traces. When i send trace to Kafka, i got it in zipkin UI, it is persistent in memory. I want to persist all traces in ES 5.0 for some time and when zipkin starts or when i search traces i want to search in ES or load trace from ES at start time of zipkin.

I start zipkin like this integrated with Kafka:

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER=kafka1:2181,kafka2:2181 KAFKA_GROUP_ID=zipkin  java -jar /opt/zipkin/bin/zipkin.jar --logging.level.zipkin=DEBUG
```

Here is [description of zipkin-storage/elasticsearch-http](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-storage/elasticsearch-http):

This is output:

```
STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch ES_HOSTS=es5_1:9200 java -jar /opt/zipkin/bin/zipkin-dependencies.jar
17/04/13 17:16:25 INFO ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Processing spans from zipkin-2017-04-13/span
17/04/13 17:16:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/13 17:16:28 INFO ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Saving dependency links to zipkin-2017-04-13/dependencylink
17/04/13 17:16:28 INFO ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Done
```

But in ES in index zipkin there are no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run 2 different applications.

To run the `zipkin` application with with ElasticSearch and Kafka you will need to run it with both sets of environment variables:

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER=kafka1:2181,kafka2:2181 KAFKA_GROUP_ID=zipkin STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch ES_HOSTS=es5_1:9200 java -jar /opt/zipkin/bin/zipkin.jar --logging.level.zipkin=DEBUG
```

Once you have the `zipkin` server running with ES, then you can use your second command to generate the data for the dependency graph view

Comment: i still got error about no node found, but is is good answer, i was blind when reading documentation. many thanks to you!

Comment: You can get support on gitter also if you need it: https://gitter.im/openzipkin/zipkin